# 'require' keyword not being recognized by webstorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm

I'm using **WebStorm** as the IDE.

Here's my folder structure and express.js insalled:

[image]

But my sample code is not aware of the **require** keyword:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.listen(1337, function(){
    console.log("ready");
});
```

Update

Per Darin's answer Here's my package.json file which now sits in the root of the Website folder:

[image]

```
{
  "name": "MyTestSite.com",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "A Website",
  "main": "test.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.11.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "n/a"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/n/a"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "express"
  ],
  "author": "My Name",
  "license": "n/a",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/n/a/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/n/a"
}
```

This was created with npm init.  I don't think I need all that crap in there so now I just have:

```
{
  "name": "MyTestSite.com",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "A Website",
  "main": "test.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.11.2"
  }
}
```

I must have something malformed here...WebStorm still doesn't recognize the require keyword.

require is a keyword for npm isn't it?

Comment: what do you mean there's code colorization here.  Here meaning what

Comment: What's exactly your question ? Why is the **unspecified** IDE unaware of the require keyword ?

Comment: The reason I had added an image originally was to show the editor showing intellisense not recognizing that keyword.

Comment: Yes that is my question, it's not the IDE, I have my node app structured wrong or something or else it would have recognized it just fine and it isn't

Comment: OK, so the question is about intellisense... That's what you should have precised in your question (and tag)

Comment: I think it's obvious that it's intellisense (which in turn means the app)....it either recognizes it or it doesn't, the app does not work period...

Comment: of course it is about the IDE. What do you think does the intellisense stuff?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In Webstorm, there are three places in your settings (`ctrl-alt-s`) where you can update settings for Node.js projects.

**Settings: Javascript Libraries**

First, in `Javascript | Libraries` you can specify that Node libraries should be loaded.  Your set of libraries may look different than this, but it should be pretty close...or, if needed, you can add the libraries so that your flavor (node, io, whatever) shows up.

[image]

**JSHint**

Second, if you have JSHint enabled, you should also enable the Node.js environment so that JSHint acts appropriately.

[image]

**Nodejs and NPM Settings**

You can (should) also set the path to your node executable.  Webstorm will also detect your globally installed modules, too, and show you if your versions are up-to-date.

[image]

**The Official Docs**

Finally, this reference link contains much more information about WebStorm and Node: [JetBrains Webstorm -- Nodejs Docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/node-js.html)

Comment: Thanks.  I did all this now.  And I still had the issue.  It wasn't until I moved my test.js file into the node_modules folder that JSHint and JSLint started to recognize the require keyword.  I don't know if that's what people do, seems kinda weird to me to have my app.js file inside node_modules?  Is that right?

Comment: No, all of the keywords (including `require`) should be recognized in your project root.  Something is still wrong or misconfigured.

Comment: This answer is out of date now unfortunately.

Comment: I wonder why jshint does not have "Node.js" enabled by default!

Answer (score 18):

Under Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Node.js and NPM, make sure "Node.js Core library is enabled" is enabled.

[image]

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 7 with latest version of WebStorm so current at June 2017.

Comment: what about a typescript react project?

Answer (score 5):

Under `Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Node.js and NPM` make sure to check `Index internal node modules`. After it's done indexing, it will recognize the require keyword.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### Update

On the new Webstorm versions, just going above error and clicking in `More Actions...` (or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>) and selecting
**Enable Node.js coding assistance** will solve this.

[image]

---

To solve these problems on the new Webstorm versions, you need to enable the **Coding assistance for Node.js**.

To do this, go on the `Settings` > `Languages & Frameworks` > `Node.js and NPM` and click on the `Coding assistance for Node.js` option, and then click **OK** to save:

[image]

This will solve all Node.js unresolved variables and functions.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have a [`package.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) file in the root of your website.

Comment: but this guy doesn't have one, why is his working?  Start at 16:36 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QseHOX-5nJQ

Comment: This guy is using Sublime Text whereas you seem to be using WebStorm. Quite a difference here. Also your code works if you run it. It's just that your IDE doesn't recognize this as a node.js project because it's the `package.json` that allows for this IDE to recognize it as such. The `package.json` is not required at runtime, you need it only to install modules.

Comment: correct I'm using WebStorm.  I should have stated that but I was not aware it made a huge diff till now.

Comment: This guy is using Sublime Text whereas you seem to be using WebStorm. Quite a difference here...what is the diff?  I'd assume an editor is an editor and you need the same kind of structure for any kind of node app.  But you are saying sublime infers stuff?

Comment: it's still not recognizing that "require" keyword.  Check out my updated post