# Npm and Node imports

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I'm having trouble understanding the usage after importing an API using NPM into my node project. Attempted using both Firebase API and icon-sdk-js. Both services give the example usage as

```
const firebaseApp = require('firebase');
```

or

```
const IconService = require('icon-sdk-js');
```

However, for both services any API function calls are unrecognized in Webstorm. When attempting to run the .js file anyways there is always an error with the require function not being recognized. Also when attempting to use the ES import syntax, it brings up errors within the files that are part of the API (located in the node_module folder).

Not sure what I'm missing or not understanding but any guidance would be very appreciated.

UPDATE:

````
const httpProvider = new HttpProvider('https://ctz.solidwallet.io/api/v3');
                     ^

ReferenceError: HttpProvider is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\treva\Dropbox\Projects\Web\bianca\js\index.js:3:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)```

-Trevor
````

Comment: Just to make sure, you're running the file using node.exe? Can you post the exact error message you're getting about `require`?

Comment: Yes, just double-checked the run configuration.

Comment: Did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28643618/require-keyword-not-being-recognized-by-webstorm

Comment: What is `HttpProvider`? Where is it declared / required?

Comment: Chris, thanks for the link. double checked my settings and the icon-sdk-js is included and the Node.js core module is included. However, when attempting to the code now, there is an import error for a file included in the icon-sdk-js.

```HttpProvider``` is a separate js file that is included in the IconService.js

Comment: You will need `const httpProvider = new IconService.HttpProvider('https://ctz.solidwallet.io/api/v3');` Or you do `const HttpProvider = IconService.HttpProvider;` first.

Comment: Chris, you solved it! The syntax still doesn't read properly but I'm guessing that has to with the project settings.

Thank you very much! not sure how to give you an upvote for a comment.